# GCM Network Manager is deprecated. Firebase Jobdispatcher is not working persistently in background?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-job-dispatcher

I heard that GCM get's deprecated on April 11, 2019. I have implemented GCM Network manager in my project, I am running service persistently in the background, though internet connectivity on or off.

Firebase job dispatcher is not running like GCM Network Manager?

This is the following code:

```
Job myJob = mDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            .setTag(JOB_TAG)
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(5, 30))
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            .build();
    mDispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.job_scheduled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: firebase job are basically for scheduling [check this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/)

Comment: I have implemented firebase job dispatcher, but still not working perfectly like GCM Network manager?

Comment: Instead of this question (which you should delete), why don’t you ask specifically what “is not working perfectly” and what have you tried that didn’t fix the problem? This is not a Code-Review site or a place to speculate with uncertainty. :)

Comment: Hi @MartinMarconcini, I have edited my question. Please check and tell me the possibility. How to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub documentation for [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) clearly states:

> This library uses the scheduling engine inside [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)(formerly the [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) component) to provide a backwards compatible (back to Gingerbread) [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)-like API.